# How can I set a value inside a foreach loop in Google Sheets App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, foreach, setvalue

1. Now the script logs rows
2. Instead of logging rows I want to set values to those rows
3. I want to change the "Logger.log" to "setValue"

   function add(){
   var mainsname ='MIIST';
   var  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var mainss = ss.getSheetByName(mainsname);
   var adcnumber = ss.getRangeByName('AD').getColumn();
   var sacnumber = ss.getRangeByName('SA').getColumn();
   var dicnumber = ss.getRangeByName('DI').getColumn();
   var range = mainss.getDataRange();
   var data = range.getValues().slice(1);
   data.forEach((row)=>{

   if(row[sacnumber-1] !== "" && row[dicnumber-1] =="" ){Logger.log(row[dicnumber-1]);}

   } )
   }

Comment: It is unclear what the desired end result is. Do you just want to log the data, or do you want to store it somewhere in the spreadsheet?

Comment: You example does not meet the requirements for [mcve] because we do not know have the nameranges are defined.  Please provide a real [mcve]

Comment: I revised the question to make it clearer

Comment: This question has been reposted in [How to make "setValue" work inside a foreach in Google Sheets App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72589451/13045193).

Answer (score 0):

To log the values in the row, use `console.log(row);`.

To append data to the end of the sheet, use `Array.filter()` and `Sheet.appendRow()`, like this:

```
  const result = data.filter(row => row[sacnumber - 1] !== '' && !row[dicnumber - 1]);
  result.forEach(row => mainss.appendRow(row));
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to log the data, instead of logging it I would like to set a value (setValue for each row)

Comment: To append data to the end of the sheet, use the second recipe I gave above. Please edit your question to explain, in detail, what the desired end result is.

Comment: I revised the question to make it clearer

Comment: Understood. To append data to the end of the sheet, replace your `data.forEach()` block with the two lines of code I gave you. If you do not want to append the data, but to write it to a fixed location, please explain, in detail, what the desired end result is.