# How to make "setValue" work inside a foreach in Google Sheets App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, foreach, setvalue

I want to set values for rows that meet the conditions that I have set via the following script:

```
function add(){
 var mainsname ='MIIST';
  var  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainss = ss.getSheetByName(mainsname);
  var adcnumber = ss.getRangeByName('AD').getColumn();
  var sacnumber = ss.getRangeByName('SA').getColumn();
  var dicnumber = ss.getRangeByName('DI').getColumn();
  var range = mainss.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues().slice(1);
  data.forEach((row)=>{

  if(row[sacnumber-1] !== "" && row[dicnumber-1] =="" ){mainss.getRange(row,dicnumber+1).setValue("test");}

  } )
}
```

The issue is that I can't get the **row number** because "row" give me the **value**, I need the row number I can use the "setValue":

> mainss.getRange(**row**,dicnumber+1).setValue("test");

Comment: You should not set values one at a time with `.setValue()`. Instead, set all values in one go with `.setValues()`. See [Apps Script best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations).

Comment: Copy of [How can I set a value inside a foreach loop in Google Sheets App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72583707/13045193).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `index` parameter, like this:

```
  data.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    const rowNumber = rowIndex + 1;
    // ...
```